# How to replace string in an element in an array with a string from an element in another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

Hi so what I am aiming to do is replace all the words in array1 (2x2) that match the words in arrayChoose (3x1) with the words in arrayReplacewith (3x1) using Javascript. I've tried several methods including mapping and replacing, but i'm going around in circles and not sure how to proceed.

edit: just to add some context, I am loading all arrays from csv files.
Also choose and replace arrays may not necessarily be the same length...

edit2: issues faced: all examples I've seen work on vectors, not matrices. Secondly, any solutions which replace the string in all the elements only replace the first instance of the string and I have not been able to implement a global replace.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
var array1 = [["today is the day","or maybe it's tomorrow"],["who knows really","it's just where we are"]];

var arrayChoose = ["today", "tomorrow", "just"];

var arrayReplacewith = ["monday", "tuesday", "not"];
```

**Solution**
Thanks to everybody who contributed their answers. I've utilised the one provided by @mohamed-ibrahim . Please see the solution below ... (arrays loaded from csv files, see [here](https://github.com/EuclidsElements/replace-array-text-01022017) for full example)

```
var arrayIncorrect = [ [ 'Trump has ordered', 'flight attendants to stop' ],
  [ 'shorter people to ', 'restrict tourism.' ],
  [ 'Now all they ', 'need is a wall.' ] ];

var dataChoose = [ [ 'Trump' ],
  [ 'stop' ],
  [ 'people' ],
  [ 'restrict' ],
  [ 'wall' ] ];

var dataReplace = [ [ 'Kim Jong-un' ],
  [ 'wear' ],
  [ 'skirts' ],
  [ 'boost' ],
  [ 'airplane' ] ];

arrayCorrect=
    arrayIncorrect.map(function(array1){
      return array1.map(function(ele){
               dataChoose.forEach(function(choose){
                 ele = ele.replace(new RegExp(choose, 'g'),  dataReplace[dataChoose.indexOf(choose)]) ;
               })
               return ele;
             })
    });

    console.log(arrayCorrect)
```

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: You're missing some commas in `array1`; the code posted would generate syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah, if you need it to be a 2x2 array it needs to be like:
var array1 = [["today is the day", "or maybe it's tomorrow"], ["who knows really", "it's just where we are"]];
Or add objects:
var array1 = [{obj1:"today is the day", obj2:"or maybe it's tomorrow"}, {obj1:"who knows really", obj2:"it's just where we are"}];

Comment: Apologies, quite right, have amended the code, thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan understood, will update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var array1 = [["today is the day","or maybe it's tomorrow"],["who knows really","it's just where we are"]];
var arrayChoose = ["today", "tomorrow", "just"];
var arrayReplacewith = ["monday", "tuesday", "not"];

array1 = 
   array1.map(function(array2){
     return array2.map(function(ele){
              arrayChoose.forEach(function(choose){
                ele = ele.replace(new RegExp(choose, 'g'),  arrayReplacewith[arrayChoose.indexOf(choose)]) ;
              })
              return ele;
            })
   });
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this answer. I am afraid I made a mistake in array1 initially and have updated it. This should be a 2x2 array. Can this code be adapted for that?

Comment: Thanks for updating this. This works for the first match in each element, but when the word is repeated and each needs to be replaced shouldn't we use the global replace?

Comment: Thanks this is perfect, I've updated my question to include an example using your answer, and ive added a link to github with an example of loading the csv files for each array.

Answer (score 1):

Two simple `map`'s will do the trick, this will potentially throw an error if the choose array has more entries than the replace array, so you need to make sure that's not the case.

```js
var array1 = ["today is the day", "or maybe it's tomorrow", "who knows really", "it's just where we are"];
var arrayChoose = ["today", "tomorrow", "just"];
var arrayReplacewith = ["monday", "tuesday", "not"];

array1 = array1.map(v => {
  let s = v.split(" ").map(st => {
    let index = arrayChoose.indexOf(st);
    return index > -1 ? arrayReplacewith[index] : st;
  });
  return s.join(" ");
});

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with ES6 [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
replaceArr = (arrOriginal, arrWordsToMatch, arrWordsToReplace) => {        
    if (arrWordsToMatch.length != arrWordsToReplace.length) throw "arrWordsToMatch and arrWordsToReplace must have exact length"
    return arrOriginal.map( (phrase) => {
        return phrase.split(" ").map( (word) => {
            let foundIndex = arrWordsToMatch.indexOf(word)
            return (foundIndex > -1) ? arrWordsToReplace[foundIndex] : word
        }).join(" ")
    })
}

let newArray = replaceArr(array1, arrayChoose, arrayReplacewith);

console.log(newArray);
/*
  [ 'monday is the day',
  'or maybe it\'s tuesday',
  'who knows really',
  'it\'s not where we are' ]
*/
```

Note: as `arrWordsToMatch` and `arrWordsToReplace` must have same length, it throws an error if the sizes are different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression and an object for the replacement strings.

```js
var array = [["today is the day", "or maybe it's tomorrow"], ["who knows really", "it's just where we are"]],
    object = { today: 'monday', tomorrow: 'tuesday', just: 'not' },
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return a.map(function(b) {
            return b.replace(RegExp(Object.keys(object).join('|'), 'g'), function (s) {
                return object[s];
            });
        });
    });

console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
var array = [["today is the day", "or maybe it's tomorrow"], ["who knows really", "it's just where we are"]],
    object = { today: 'monday', tomorrow: 'tuesday', just: 'not' },
    result = array.map(a => a.map(b => b.replace(RegExp(Object.keys(object).join('|'), 'g'), s => object[s])));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for this answer. The issue with using an object is that I am loading all arrays from a csv file and so this could not work. I have also updated array1 in the question as this needs to be a 2x2 or greater array and I had written it incorrectly before.